# Фрагмент кода python для получения погоды с помощью библиотеки pyowm

Tags: python, pyowm

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('dbf1c716cecbf43263218e4e0505968c', language='ru')
print(type(owm))
while True:
    place = input('В каком городе/стране?: ')


    observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
    w = observation.get_weather()


    temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']

    print('В городе ' + place + " сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status())
    print('Температура сейчас в районе ' + str(temp))

print(type(observation)) # выдает следующее:
                         # <class 'pyowm.weatherapi25.observation.Observation'>

print(type(w)) # выдает следующее:
               # <class 'pyowm.weatherapi25.weather.Weather'>
```

Каким образом observation оказывается экземпляром observation.Observation а w экземпляром weather.Weather,если в коде:

```
observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.get_weather()
```

Comment: Очень просто: очевидно, метод `weather_at_place` возвращает объект класса `observation.Observation`, а метод `get_weather` возвращает объект класса `weather.Weather`. Если хотите подробностей - откройте исходники и посмотрите как там реализовано.

Comment: def get_weather(self):
        """
        Returns the *Weather* object for this observation

        :returns: the *Weather* object

        """
        return self._weather Спасибо за совет, но можно узнать на примере этого метода из класса Observation, каким образом он возвращает объект Weather?

Comment: Любой метод может возвращать объект любого класса: например, создать объект и сразу вернуть его через return.